# Custom Calculator with Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I have some problem to create a custom calculator. I follow the instructions here:

http://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/calculators.html.

I have my calculator inside spree/calculator:

```
class CustomCalculator < Spree::Calculator
  def self.description
    # Human readable description of the calculator
  end

  def compute(object=nil)
    p "Test"
    10.0
    # Returns the value after performing the required calculation
  end
end
```

and in spree.rb I added:

```
config = Rails.application.config
config.spree.calculators.tax_rates << CustomCalculator
```

but when I run the server, I receive this server:

```
config/initializers/spree.rb:24:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant CustomCalculator (NameError)
```

I already looked around and tries different ways to create my custom calculator... but nothing was right.

I'm using Spree 3.1.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have your calculator inside spree/calculator, do scope it under Spree::Calculator:

```
module Spree
  class Calculator::CustomCalculator < Calculator
    def self.description
      # Human readable description of the calculator
    end

    def compute(object=nil)
      p "Test"
      10.0
      # Returns the value after performing the required calculation
    end
  end
end
```

and in spree.rb add:

```
Spree::Core::Engine.config.after_initialize do
  config = Rails.application.config
  config.spree.calculators.tax_rates << Spree::Calculator::CustomCalculator
end
```

Comment: If I write as you said, I have this error: <top (required)>': undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Comment: "tax_rates" seems to be nil

Comment: Just wrap the config in an  `Spree::Core::Engine.config.after_initialize` block like this:
```Spree::Core::Engine.config.after_initialize do
  config = Rails.application.config
  config.spree.calculators.tax_rates << Spree::Calculator::CustomCalculator
end```

preferably in `config/initializers/spree.rb`.

Comment: @Mauro did this help? If it did, do upvote the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a file with class_name in `models/spree/calculators` folder

```rb
    module Spree
      class Calculator::CustomCalculator < Calculator
        def self.description
          # Human readable description of the calculator
        end

        def compute(object=nil)
          p "Test"
          10.0
          # Returns the value after performing the required calculation
        end
      end
    end
```

2. In spree.rb add `Rails.application.config.spree.calculators.tax_rates << Spree::Calculator::CustomCalculator`